# Difference between drop cache through shell command and "clear cache" button in application

Tags: android, caching, clear-cache, difference

anyone can explain what's the different between drop cache with this code : `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and the classic "Clear cache" button in the app information? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that is the same is the existence of the word "cache" in each.

`drop_caches` refers to Linux kernel page caching, near as I can tell. It is certainly well outside the bounds of what anyone with any sense would mess with in an Android app.

"Clear Cache" refers to files stored in per-application cache directories (`getCacheDir()` and `getExternalCacheDir()`).